# this.setState is not working for multiple text input in react-native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

```js
    {
      element.answers_data.map((answer, index) =>
          <View key={index} style={{paddingLeft: 20}}>
          <TextInput
            value = {answer.answer_text}
             onChangeText={(answer_text) => {
               this.setState({answer_text: answer_text});
             }}
            />
          </View>
    )}
```

I am using TextInput in array. But it is not working. Please provide any solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text inputs is an array, you should make its reflecting `state` an array too:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        answers: element.answers_data.map( (answer, index) => {
            return answer.answer_text
        }),
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
        {
        element.answers_data.map((answer, index) =>
            <View key={index} style={{paddingLeft: 20}}>
                <TextInput
                    value = {this.state.answers[index]}
                    onChangeText={(answer_text) => {
                        /// Since state is immutable, construct a new array for modified answer for specific index.
                        this.setState({
                            answers: [
                                ...this.state.answers.slice(0, index),
                                answer_text,
                                ...this.state.answers.slice(index+1, this.state.answers.length)
                            ]
                        });
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
        }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Since state is immutable, you cannot just change the array value with index.
Check code for example to construct a new array for modified `answer`.

Comment: than you so much for your response. its working properly. i have just replaced **this.state.answers.length-1**  with **this.state.answers.length** and its working fine.

Comment: Yes, was busy and just found it. that's awesome you found it too! corrected my code =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with multiple inputs change the same one state field?
May you should separate?
About is not working, what do you mean, the component updates but state doesn't change, callback doesn't invoke, you get always the same answer_text, or something else?